# Getting a non-descript CSS parsing error when attempting to run create-react-app build

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

Im using a pretty basic CSS file to style my react app, but when I attempt to run `npm run build` on it, I am getting a parse error on line 1, column 35.

This is the part that is causing the issue:

```
@keyframes jiggleLink {
  0%, 100%{
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  }
  25%{
    transform: translate(var(--jiggle-skew), 0);
  }
  75%{
    transform: translate(calc(var(--jiggle-skew)*-1), 0);
  }
}
```

Why might this be causing errors?

Comment: What `build` script does?

Comment: @Anastazy It’s a built in function of create-react-app, so idk

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this specific fragment of your final `transform` rule: `)*-1`. You need to separate the operator from the multiplier for the compiler to parse it correctly since you are using a negative value which could also be interpreted as a `-` operator.

Just changing it to `)* -1` would do the trick, however in the interests of consistency with the way the CSS calc function is supposed to be used (it will fail in the browser with invalid syntax when the `+` or `-` operators are not surrounded by whitespace), this is probably better:

```
transform: translate(calc(var(--jiggle-skew) * -1), 0);
```